# How to Access Google Googles API or Google Search by Image API

Tags: android, google-api, google-image-search

Would be great, if someone suggest me a way to access Google Googles API or Google Search by Image API.

Currently seems that Google doesn't incentive the use of this API for third parts developers unlike the others Google APIs.

The image search in Google site has a button with a camera that allows the user to upload an image and start a search by image content, if the Google Googles API are not accessible directly, maybe, a good idea might be parsing the Google Search by Image page code and implement a system that access this service through Google Site.

A way to access this function in an app would give to developers infinite possibility to make new awesome apps.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these features use internal APIs that are not publicly accessible. They're not intended to be used by software that you write.

If you tinker around, you might be able to reverse engineer them, but I'd recommend against it. Any code you write that depends on them can break at any time without warning.